# 有益な内容なら転載が許容されるというモデレータ判断について

Tags: 討議

[バイトコンパイルってどういう時に使うんですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20216/)という質問への[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/20223/5793)はpythonのドキュメントの抜粋による転載であることから、モデレータ通報で著作権の問題がある旨通報したところ、「有益な内容なので問題ない」という理由で却下されました。

有益なら転載が許容されるというモデレータ判断の根拠となるような明文化されたルールはどこかに定義されていますか?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

その通報に対応したのは私ですが、

- 他のユーザーがプラス投票していることからも、件の転載部分が質問に対する有益な情報と見受けられるため、別の形で残すべきではないか
- 投稿者のミスだとすれば、投稿者に指摘し、投稿者自身で修正してもらうのが理想的
- 現状、このことを指摘するコメント等は行われていない

という理由から、モデレーター権限で直ちに削除するのではなく、「まずコメントでそのことを指摘されてはいかがでしょうか」とお返事しました。

代理で私がコメントやメタ投稿を行うことも考えましたが、問題と感じた本人に書いてもらった方が的確な指摘ができるのではないか、そしてモデレーターを通さずに行動を起こしてもいいのだと伝える意味合いも含め、このような形を選択した次第です。

通報をdeclineしたのはこういう理由からであり、「有益な内容なので問題ない」というつもりはありませんでした。明文化もされていないでしょう。ですから、指摘しても投稿者による改善が見られないのであれば、投稿の削除ないしは適切な形への編集（これは皆さんでも行えますが）を行うことも考えていました。

---

> まずいことになるのは投稿者とStackExchangeであって私含めて他のユーザーではない

まずいことというと司法的な話だと思いますが、投稿者は利用規約で権利上問題のあるコンテンツを投稿しないことに同意しているわけですし、正式な請求は[DMCA](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9F%E3%83%AC%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A0%E8%91%97%E4%BD%9C%E6%A8%A9%E6%B3%95)に則って権利者が行うことになるでしょうから、モデレーターはおろか社員ですら先行して対応する義務はないはずです。

ヘルプセンターには以下の記述がありますが、これはサイトのローカルルールでしかありません。

> 盗用 (他者の著作物を、自分のものではないということを示さずに投稿すること) は、コミュニティのひんしゅくを買い、回答に反対投票が集まったり削除されたりする場合があります。
>   <sub>--- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing より引用</sub>

ローカルルールを守らないユーザーに対して、そのことを注意したり、代わりに修正したり、といったことはモデレーター以外のユーザーにもできることです。これらの**信用度さえあれば誰にでもできることで対応しきれない場合にのみ**、投稿の削除、メールによる警告、当該ユーザーによる投稿制限といったモデレーター特権を発動する方がよいと、私は考えています。

参考

- [Can we have documentation on copyright and fair-use with regards to improving link-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219736/286934)
- [Quoting content from external sites - is this considered "fair use"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113559/286934)

Comment: まずいことになるのは投稿者とStackExchangeであって私含めて他のユーザーではないので、モデレータがその権限をもって「対処の必要なし」と判断されるのであれば、一ユーザーとしてそれ以上やるべき事はありません。ただ、「有益な内容であれば転載が許容される」というのは特異なポリシーなので、それが明文化されているかどうかを尋ねています。

Comment: @suzukis そのようなポリシーを意図したわけではない、ということを書き忘れていたので一部書き直しました。また転載に対する対応についても追記しています。

Comment: 転載を許容する趣旨ではないということなので、その点については了解です。